# Lists in functions and classes python

Tags: python, list

How can you use one list that any function in that class can access. For example, in my class student, I want to create a list called grades, and I want to create separate functions to add to the list, remove from the list, ect.

Comment: Look into `static` methods/functions.

Comment: You don't have to do anything. If you don't overwrite it, you'll be accessing the instance in the class

Answer (score 2):

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.grades = []


myStudent = Student()

myStudent.grades.append(90)
```

This question is very basic. Have you gone through a [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)?

Comment: what if I want to remove() in a different function? Do I say self.grades.remove(x) in the other function or can I just say grades.remove(x)

Also, I do not what to call the list from outside the class, anything I add/remove to the list will be from inside the functions themselves. so would I still need to say "self."?

Comment: yes I have, I am in a python class now trying to understand how to use one list in multiple functions in a class. I did try what you suggested above, I cannot create a remove grade function that calls remove() to the list grades...

Comment: @user1207457 Yes, you need to use `self.grades` in all the methods (presuming they take their first parameter with the name `self`, as is conventional). This is how Python works; you *always* need to specify an object in which to look for an attribute. Only local and global variables can be accessed with a bare name like `grades`. I would second Francis' recommendation to work through a Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> class Student(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.grades = []
...     def foo1(self):
...         self.grades.append(1)
...     def foo2(self):
...         self.grades.append(2)
...
>>> student = Student()
>>> student.foo1()
>>> student.grades
[1]
>>> student.foo2()
>>> student.grades
[1, 2]
```

As you can see there are two methods that access the same list, `grades`.  You can create another method to remove an item from `grades`, too.

Comment: is there a way I can print the list after the append() or remove() in foo1 or foo2 without having to say student.grades to print the new list?

Comment: Sure, you can add `print self.grades` inside `foo1()` or `foo2()`.